# Eclipse - My Own Classes in the Imports?

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a few classes that I want to use in many applications, so my question is quite straightforward:

**Q:** How can I add my own classes to Eclipse (or to the JDK?) and have them easily / automatically imported like the default Java Libraries?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pack these `classes` (.class files) using [JAR](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html) utility tool and add that .jar file  (say sample.jar) into your project `(Properties + Java Build Path + Add External JARS).`

Comment: Don't forget to add import statements where you want to use your classes (but Eclipse will do that half-automatically for you).